# Display selected tables with their coulm_name on different columns

Tags: sql, sybase

I have two tables `TMP` and `TMP1` so I want to select from syscolumns and get the column name for the 2 tables
I want to have such result

```
tablename columnname  tablename1 columnname1

Tmp         col1        TMP1         col1

Tmp         col2        TMP1         col2
```

this what I tried to do which is wrong:

```
select sc.name , sc1.name
from syscolumns sc inner join syscolumns sc1
on( sc.id=sc1.id and sc.id=object_id('TMP1'))
where sc.id=object_id('TMP')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: the example seems to imply the tables have the same number of columns and that said columns have the same names; what are you expecting the output to look like if the tables have a different number of columns? how do you plan to match columns that have different names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- this is Sybase ASE
- tables have the same number of columns
- column names are the same in the 2 tables

Setup:

```
create table TMP (col1 int, col2 int)
go
create table TMP1(col1 iny, col2 int)
go
```

There are a couple ways to do this but we'll tweak the given query:

```
select  'TMP' as tablename,
        sc.name as columnname,
        'TMP1' as tablename1,
        sc1.name as columname1

        -- can't join syscolumns on 'id' because each table has a unique object id;
        -- only thing we have to join on is the similarly named columns

from    syscolumns sc
join    syscolumns sc1
on      sc.name = sc1.name

where   sc.id  = object_id('TMP')
and     sc1.id = object_id('TMP1')

order by sc.name
go

 tablename columnname tablename1 columname1
 --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 TMP       col1       TMP1       col1
 TMP       col2       TMP1       col2
```

The above code was tested on a ASE 15.7 SP138 dataserver.